# Append one file to another using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, join, append

All the FFMPEG examples show how to take file1 + file2 and write result to the file3.

Is FFMPEG just able to open file1, seek to the end and then append file2, without creating the third, intermediate, file?

I would like to make a Windows Explorer context menu item. Each run of this item will append the clicked file to a file with specific name.

Answer (score 0):

We may use `pipe:` as output, and `>>` shell operator for appending.

Example for appending `input2.ts` to the end of `input1.ts`:

```
ffmpeg -i input2.ts -c copy -f mpegts pipe: >> input1.ts
```

Comment: I wonder if that's better than `cat`.

Comment: @TomYan it is probably worst than `cat`. It may be useful when the appended file requires re-encoding or format conversion. The OP didn't specify the reason for using FFmpeg for the job...

Comment: I updated the question with the aim of all this.

Comment: @Paul But what is the reason for using FFmpeg for the concatenation operation?

Comment: Rotem: Simplicity. One click operation. FFMPEG is good and effective at processing videos.